# Use of Contains inside a Select expression

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a CheckboxList where the roles of a User are Checked, and show all Available option, the UI is ok. But the the following code not working.

```
        var applicationUser = db.AspNetUsers.Include(x => x.AspNetRoles)
                              .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id.Value);

        if (applicationUser == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }


        var model = new ViewModels.UsuarioViewModel();

        model.Id = applicationUser.Id;
        model.UserName = applicationUser.UserName;
        model.Name = applicationUser.Name;
        model.Email = applicationUser.Email;
        model.EmailConfirmed = applicationUser.EmailConfirmed;
        model.PhoneNumber = applicationUser.PhoneNumber;
        model.PhoneNumberConfirmed = applicationUser.PhoneNumberConfirmed;
        model.Active = applicationUser.Active;


        model.RolesList = db.AspNetRoles.Select(r => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Selected =
                               applicationUser.AspNetRoles.Contains(x => x.Id == r.Id),
                                Text = r.Name,
                                Value = r.Name
                            }).ToList();
        return View(model);
```

The RolesList is a IEnumerable SelectListItem

The problem is the "selected = applicationUser.AspNetRoles.Contains(x => x.Id == r.Id)" part.

**Edit:**

Ok, now i have a working code:

```
model.RolesList = db.AspNetRoles.ToList().Select(r => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Selected = (applicationUser.AspNetRoles.
                                           Where(x => x.Id == r.Id).ToList().Count > 0),
                                //Selected = false,
                                Text = r.Name,
                                Value = r.Name
                            });
```

I could not make it work using Contains.

I wish to know if are a way to use contains in this expression. Where + Count looks wrong.

Comment: Is the result of the boolean you're assigning itself ok? I mean, is the problem with setting the property or is it in the expression? Why don't you debug a bit before posting

Comment: @D.Petrov The expression is wrong, i could not make it using contains.

The ways it was throw a compilation error, debug was not a option.

Changing to a "Selected = false" worked, and after i could make work using Where + Count...

Also add a ToList() before the Select to use linq in a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont want contains, you want `any`

```
Selected = applicationUser.AspNetRoles.Any(x => x.Id == r.Id),
```

`contains` looks to see if a given element is in the collection, not the same thing at all, I am surprised your code even compiled